# Parse - How to update tableView as more data is added to the parse database?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My question is to do with the backend service parse. So far, whenever I need something, I use a PFQuery to query the database. However, I now need something a little different, and have run into a slight wall.

I have a game app that records the all time high scores. Now, I want the app to auto-update the table of high scores as more come in. For example, if the first row is currently "Jimmy: 2505" and in parse suddenly another bit of data is added where Sam gets 2604, I want Sam to be at the top of the table now.

I realise that I could just continuously send a query to Parse say every 30 seconds to check for new data, but that would be terribly inefficient, and also expensive. Is there any way that I can use that allows auto-updating without sending a query all the time? Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into Parse Push https://parse.com/products/push

Comment: Thankyou, I'm aware of parse push, however I thought this was something you would do manually, i.e log onto parse and send a push notification to your users. Can push be triggered programatically aswell?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using push notifications. When the user opens the app, or uses a particular view controller, subscribe them to a channel that calls for updates when the high score list is updated. In your app delegate configure how you want the push notifications to be handled. You'll have to weigh the pros and cons of api requests generated using push notifications vs a default call to update the high score list every 30 seconds as you suggested in the OP.

Push notifications should be triggered through cloud code. When a new high score is generated make a cloud call that triggers the push notifications. You can specify the kind of push notification that you'll be sending.

Comment: Thankyou so much for this. I'm reasonably apt at using Parse Core, but I've never really delved into the push side. I've checked the documentation but there doesn't seem to be much about using push in this way to scan the database for updates and then send a push to a specific user when there needs to be a refresh. Are there any resources/code examples you would be kind enough to point me to? Many thanks!

Comment: How are you determining when a new high score is achieved?

Comment: Currently I'm saving the score to parse, running a query to get back the first object only, ordered by highest score, then comparing that to the current high score user. if it's by a different user, there's a new high score

Comment: I can find you some sample code but first I need to know how you plan on sending push notifications? I send mine via the cloud because client push can be hacked easily.

Comment: that would be amazing. I guess the cloud for me too then!